# Best practice/design pattern to control spring batch job execution/scheduling

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

We have few job which are dependent on each other where job 2 cannot start until job 1 completes like wise job 4 cannot start until job 3 completes. Is there any best practice to follow this? All this jobs have some kind of polling to either file system or db, so I am thinking of using spring integration to send job launch events but my confusion is, should I package all them together and have one parent spring integration application context which can control the job execution  or not?

Open to best practice as this we might add 3-4 more jobs later in the project. Also in future we might implement some kind of dashboard to show the status of each job and why it didnt started etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite straightforward with Spring Integration to chain a number of job launching gateways so that jobs run after each other

```
...->JLG1->transformResult1->JLG2->transformResult2->...
```

etc

The jobs can be defined in their own configuration files and imported into the main flow.

You can use the spring batch admin REST API to view job statuses etc.

Or, consider deploying your jobs in Spring XD containers and control the whole thing with the XD Admin REST API by launching the first job, and monitor the job events to determine when the next job should be started. Again, Spring Integration can be used to drive the whole sequence of jobs.

Spring XD also has a REST API (and User Interface) to examine job statuses.

See [the XD documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/) for more information.